# PHP session_write_close() continues even when Postman connection is closed

Tags: php

I'm working on a Laravel 10 project written in PHP 8.1, I have a long polling request whic makes a certain number of maximum iterations in conjunction with checking my model's status.

The trouble I've got is that when I make a request to my endpoint in Postman, the connection begins and it waits as it should. If I cancel the Postman connection at any point, I cannot start another one, and in the background, my for-loop is still running as I can see my `Log::debug()` outputting.

I've tried putting `session_write_close()` at the start of my project, but it's not kileld.

What am I missing here?

```php
/**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        session_write_close();

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'AffId' => 'required|string',
            'ApiKey' => 'required|string',
            'Application' => 'required|array',
        ]);

        // validate the request
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return new ApiValidationErrorResponse(null, '', [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Invalid',
                    'Message' => 'Invalid application request provided. Please check form errors.',
                    'Errors' => $validator->messages(),
                ],
            ]);
        }

        $submittedAt = Carbon::now();
        $productSlug = $request->input('product_slug', 'payday');
        $countrySlug = $request->input('country_slug', 'united-kingdom');

        // get the affiliate that is enabled and allows application submissions,
        // also get the affiliate products where the product matches the product_slug
        // and the country matches the country_slug, these both must be enabled
        // and if they can't be found, attempt to find the default of each.
        $affiliate = Affiliate::where('aff_id', $request->input('AffId'))
                                ->where('allow_submission', true)
                                ->where('is_enabled', true)
                                ->with([
                                    'products' => function ($query) use ($productSlug, $countrySlug) {
                                        $query->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($productSlug) {
                                            $q->where('slug', $productSlug)
                                                ->orWhere('is_default', true)
                                                ->where('is_enabled', true);
                                        })->whereHas('country', function ($q) use ($countrySlug) {
                                            $q->where('slug', $countrySlug)
                                                ->orWhere('is_default', true)
                                                ->where('is_enabled', true);
                                        });
                                    },
                                    'products.product',
                                    'products.country',
                                    'products.serve_method',
                                    'products.application_form',
                                    'products.pingtree_group',
                                ])
                                ->first();

        if (! $affiliate || (isset($affiliate) && count($affiliate->products) <= 0)) {
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Invalid',
                    'Message' => 'Unknown affiliate product data.'
                ],
            ], 404);
        }

        try {

            // generate API key from request
            $generatedApiKey = $this->generateAffiliateApiKey(
                $request->input('AffId'),
                $request->input('ApiKey')
            );

            // validate the generated API key against the affiliate's API key.
            if ($generatedApiKey['api_key'] !== $affiliate->api_key) {
                return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                    'legacy_response' => [
                        'Result' => 'Invalid',
                        'Message' => 'Authentication error. Please check credentials.',
                    ],
                ], 401);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Error authenticating AffId.',
                ],
            ]);
        }

        // map the products to a single product since in the case of
        // this controller, there can only be one anyway.
        try {
            $affiliate->affiliate_product = $affiliate->products->first();
            unset($affiliate->products);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Error mapping product.',
                ],
            ]);
        }

        // country code, with some basic formatting in case it was missed in saving
        $country = $affiliate->affiliate_product->country->country_code;
        $country = trim(strtoupper($country));

        // product type, with some basic formatting in case it was missed in saving
        $product = $affiliate->affiliate_product->product->slug;
        $product = $this->generateModelClassFromSlug(trim($product));

        // validate the application based on the product & country as this is dynamic
        try {
            $validationClass = "App\\Validation\\Applications\\$country\\$product\\Validation";

            // if class can't be found, throw error.
            if (! class_exists($validationClass)) {
                throw new \Exception("Validation class '$validationClass' cannot be found.");
            }

            // init the validation class for this country/product
            $validator = new $validationClass($request);
            $validator = $validator->init();

            // validate the form data
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return new ApiValidationErrorResponse(null, '', [
                    'legacy_response' => [
                        'Result' => 'Invalid',
                        'Message' => 'Invalid application data provided. Please check form errors.',
                        'Errors' => $validator->messages(),
                    ],
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Error validating product and or country.',
                ],
            ]);
        }

        // create the model class
        $modelableClass = \App\Models\Application::class.$country.$product;

        // if model class can't be found, throw error.
        if (! class_exists($modelableClass)) {
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Unable to obtain product information.',
                ],
            ], 404);
        }

        // create the model class
        $providerClass = "App\\ApplicationProviders\\$country\\".$product;

        // if class can't be found, throw error.
        if (! class_exists($providerClass)) {
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Unable to obtain provider information.',
                ],
            ], 404);
        }

        try {

            $transaction = DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $affiliate, $providerClass, $modelableClass, $submittedAt) {

                // generate metadata about application
                $threadUUID = (string) Str::uuid();

                // define fields for linking
                $linkFields = [
                    'user_id' => $affiliate->user_id,
                    'company_id' => $affiliate->company_id,
                    'country_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->country->id,
                    'product_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->product->id,
                    'serve_method_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->serve_method->id,
                    'application_form_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->application_form->id,
                    'pingtree_group_id' => $affiliate->affiliate_product->pingtree_group->id,
                    'affiliate_id' => $affiliate->id,
                ];

                $userAgent = $request->userAgent();
                if ($request->input('Application.client_user_agent_string')) {
                    $userAgent = $request->input('Application.client_user_agent_string');
                }

                $ip = $request->ip();
                if ($request->input('Application.ReqUPAddress')) {
                    $ip = $request->input('Application.ReqUPAddress');
                }

                $brand = $request->input('brand', null);
                if ($request->input('Application.brand')) {
                    $brand = $request->input('Application.brand');
                }

                $campaign = $request->input('campaign', null);
                if ($request->input('Application.SubAffId')) {
                    $campaign = $request->input('Application.SubAffId');
                }

                // application data
                $applicationData = array_merge([
                    'thread_uuid' => $threadUUID,
                    'status' => ApplicationStatus::PENDING,
                    'affiliate' => $affiliate->aff_id,
                    'brand' => $brand,
                    'campaign' => $campaign,
                    'ip' => $ip,
                    'user_agent' => $userAgent,
                    'fingerprint' => $request->fingerprint(),
                    'submitted_at' => $submittedAt,
                ], $linkFields);

                // create application instance
                $application = Application::create($applicationData);

                // init a new provider class instance
                $provider = new $providerClass($request);

                // create modelable data
                $modelable = $modelableClass::create(array_merge(
                    $provider->getMappedApplication(),
                    $linkFields
                ))->application()->save($application);

                // the response to return
                $returnResponse = [
                    'thread_uuid' => $threadUUID,
                    'provider' => $provider,
                ];

                // dispatch to Processor
                if (config('queue.default') == 'redis') {
                    ProcessApplication::dispatch($threadUUID)
                                      ->onConnection('redis');

                    return $returnResponse;
                }

                // fallback to non-redis setup
                ProcessApplication::dispatch($threadUUID);
                return $returnResponse;
            });

            // are we processing?
            $maxRuntimeSeconds = 600;

            // give application chance to process, and also provide a
            // maximum timeout.
            for ($k = 1 ; $k < $maxRuntimeSeconds; $k++) {
                Log::debug('still running...');
                sleep(1);

                // check application
                $checkedApplication = $transaction['provider']->getCheckedApplication($transaction['thread_uuid']);

                // success!
                if (boolval($checkedApplication['complete'])) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // return response
            return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
                'legacy_response' => $checkedApplication
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new ApiErrorResponse($e, [
                'legacy_response' => [
                    'Result' => 'Error',
                    'Message' => 'Error submitting application, please try again soon.',
                ],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would `session_write_close` have to do with "killing" your for loop?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I've opened a question on here for assistance.

Comment: session_write_close would fix issues with the session data file having a write lock, as long as one script instance is still using the session - so all others will have to wait, until that lock is released. But it is unclear how the termination of your loop is supposed to work here, we don't know what your `getCheckedApplication` method there does.